# Present period in a string without negative numbers

Tags: java, jodatime

in a joda-time based project I am trying to present the user with the period between 2 dates in a readable format.
I do not succeed to retrieve this period without negative values. The following code fragment shows the issue:

```
LocalDateTime firstTime = new LocalDateTime( 2014, 10, 15, 4, 42 );
LocalDateTime secondTime = new LocalDateTime( 2014, 12, 3, 5, 5 );

Period period = Period.fieldDifference(firstTime, secondTime).normalizedStandard();
```

The output of of `period.toString()`is:

```
P2M-1W-4DT-23H-37M
```

I'm looking for the best method to get something the period in a format like:

`P1M3W` etc. instead of the negative values?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: @ReutSharabani they aren't separators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace Period.fieldDifference for new Period.
try with this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDateTime firstTime = new LocalDateTime(2014, 10, 15, 4, 42);
    LocalDateTime secondTime = new LocalDateTime(2014, 12, 3, 5, 5);

    System.out.println("period Type: "+Period.fieldDifference(firstTime, secondTime).getPeriodType());
    Period period = new Period(firstTime, secondTime).normalizedStandard();
    System.out.println(period);
}
```

Comment: Hi David, many thinks this solved it, the output is now: P1M2W4DT23M.